# Setting default values for params in Rails 4 when the user leaves a form field blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a DataPoint model and a form that allows the user to enter the age range and income range of the datapoints they want to see.

In data_points_controller.rb:

```
def result
    @data_points = DataPoint.select_subset(params[:min_income], params[:max_income], params[:min_age], params[:max_age])
end
```

And in the model data_point.rb:

```
def self.select_subset(min_income, max_income, min_age, max_age)
    DataPoint.where("annual_income BETWEEN :min_income AND :max_income AND age BETWEEN :min_age AND :max_age", {min_income: min_income, max_income: max_income, min_age: min_age, max_age: max_age})
end
```

This works fine when the user enters all 4 inputs: min_income, max_income, min_age and max_age.  The correct subset of the data is returned with summary statistics.

However, when the user leaves any of the 4 inputs blank, I get an error:

```
Computation results to 'NaN'(Not a Number)
```

When a user omits a particular parameter, I'd like for the query to run as if there were no constraint on that particular parameter.

I took a look at the database and realized none of the ages are outside 0-100, so I tried:

```
def result
    params[:min_age] ||= "0"
    params[:max_age] ||= "100"
    @data_points = DataPoint.select_subset(params[:min_income], params[:max_income], params[:min_age], params[:max_age])
end
```

But I am still getting the above-mentioned error.

Any ideas how I can get this working correctly even when the user doesn't fill out all 4 form fields?

Thanks!

Comment: so why not to set default values for `min_income` and `max_income` params aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being not sure about presence of all of the passed attributes, you could rewrite your SQL query to include only those restrictions which have values from user:

```
def self.select_subset(min_income, max_income, min_age, max_age)
  conditions = [].tap do |array|
    array << "annual_income >= :min_income" if min_income.present?
    array << "annual_income <= :max_income" if max_income.present?
    array << "age >= :min_age" if min_age.present?
    array << "age <= :max_age" if max_age.present?
  end

  named_params = {min_income: min_income, max_income: max_income, min_age: min_age, max_age: max_age}
  DataPoint.where(conditions.join(' AND '), named_params)
end
```

Note that you should handle the case when user did not select any restriction at all somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> `||=` set a variable's value if its value were 'Nothing' (`false` or `nil` in Ruby)

However, if the params is blank (`""`) it will keep it blank.

```
a = ""
#=> ""
a ||= "foo"
#=> ""
```

So, try the following:

```
def result
  params[:min_age] = "0"   if params[:min_age].blank?
  params[:max_age] = "100" if params[:max_age].blank?
  @data_points = DataPoint.select_subset(params[:min_income], params[:max_income], params[:min_age], params[:max_age])
end
```

The [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) will cover `nil` and `""`.